# Finding a degree 1 elliptic function by relaxing conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

> **Review**: A doubly-periodic meromorphic function $f$, or an elliptic function, has a degree $d$ defined to be the sum of the orders of the poles in its fundamental parallelogram $\Gamma$. As $z$ ranges over the $\Gamma$, $f(z)$ winds over the Riemann sphere $d$ times. Elliptic functions must have degree $d>1$.

For physics reasons, I would really like to have an "almost elliptic" function of degree $d=1$. I can't give up periodicity, but I can give up strict meromorphicity everywhere.

**Is there such a function which is meromorphic outside a measure zero set?** The measure zero set could be $\partial \Gamma$ for instance. Or can you prove you can't have it?

More generally, **can you provide an "almost" elliptic function with degree $d=1$** for a suitable interpretation of "almost"?

Comment: The Weierstrass zeta function $\zeta_\Lambda$ is the primitive of $\wp_\Lambda$, it is meromorphic with only one simple pole by parallelogram, it is not $\Lambda$ periodic but $\zeta_\Lambda(z+\lambda)-\zeta_\Lambda(z)$ is constant for each $\lambda\in \Lambda$.

Comment: Jacobian theta functions $\vartheta_r(z)$ for $r=1,2,3,4$ might also be some interesting functions for you.

Comment: A probably non-interesting way: Take any meromorphic function $f$ with a single pole in some parallelogram, like the half open square $\{a+bi\mid a,b\in[0,1)\}$. Then redefine it outside of this square to make it doubly periodic: $g(x+iy):=f(x-\lfloor x\rfloor+i(y-\lfloor y\rfloor).$ This $g$ is trivially doubly periodic, but its behavior along the borders is random. But those borders form a countable union of measure zero sets, hence measure zero.